# Connect GIMP snap to gmic

Tags: snap, plugins, gimp, paths

So I have installed the GIMP snap, it works nicely. However, how do I get it to use gmic? Can I just point the plugin path to gmic, and where would that be?

Comment: /home/me/.config/gmic does not bring gmic up in the GIMP snap, FYI.